# Error in validation of Enquiryform in PHP

Tags: php, validation

In my Enquiry form in PHP, some fields can not be validate like email and phone Number. Here, I have written validation code as below:

```
function validated()    
{    
    var txt = document.frm;         
    if(txt.name.value == '')    
    {    
        alert("Please Enter Your Name.");    
        txt.name.focus();    
        return false;   
    }    
    if(txt.companyname.value == '')    
    {
        alert("Please Enter Your Company Name.");    
        txt.companyname.focus();    
        return false;    
    }    
    if ((txt.name.value.length < 4) || (txt.name.value.length > 20))    
    {    
    alert("Please Enter  Name between 4 to 20 chrecters");    
        txt.name.focus();    
        return false;    
    }    
    if(txt.city.value == '')    
    {    
        alert("Please Enter Your City.");    
        txt.city.focus();    
        return false;    
    }               
    if(txt.code.value == '')    
    {    
        alert("Please Enter Your Zip Code");    
        txt.code.focus();    
        return false;   
    }    
    if(txt.address.value == '')    
    {    
        alert("Please Enter Your Address");
        txt.address.focus();    
        return false;    
    }    
    if(txt.v_country.value == '')    
    {    
        alert("Select the country");    
        txt.v_country.focus();    
        return false;   
    }   
    if(txt.email.value == '')    
    {    
        alert("Please Enter Email-id.");   
        txt.email.focus();   
        return false;    
    }    
    else{    
        if((txt.email.value.indexOf('.',0) == '-1') || (txt.email.value.indexOf('@',0) == '-1'))   
        {    
            alert("Invalid Email-Id, Please Enter Valid Email-Id");   
            txt.email.focus();    
            return false;    
        }               
    }    
    if(txt.telephone.value == '')    
    {   
        alert("Please Enter Your Mobile Number");    
        txt.telephone.focus();    
        return false;    
    }    
    if((!txt.telephone.value.match(/^\d+/)))    
    {    
        alert("Please Enter digits only in mobile number");    
        txt.telephone.focus();    
        return false;   
    }   
    if ((txt.telephone.value.length != 10))    
    {   
        alert("Please Enter valid mobile number");    
        txt.telephone.focus();    
        return false;    
    }    
    if(txt.comment.value == '')    
    {    
        alert("Please Enter Your Description");    
        txt.comment.focus();    
        return false;    
    }    
    if(txt.verif_box.value == '')    
    {   
        alert("Please Enter varificationn code");   
        txt.verif_box.focus();   
        return false;    
    }



}
```

Comment: what do you mean by email and phone can not be validated?? Please elaborate

Comment: I think beside this validation code add where you linked it too

Comment: Ok i add contact form code also here..

Comment: In my contact form, if you don't write name then it will ask for name but its not ask for phone number..if phone number is blank then also form submitted.

Comment: perhaps remove the carat (^) from the regex pttn